# TSQL Performance issues using DATEADD in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-express

I have a query using the DATEADD method which takes a lot of time.
I'll try to simplify what we do.
We are monitoring tempretures and every 5 minutes we store the highest temp and lowest temp in 
table A

Date          |  Time      | MaxTemp | MinTemp
2011-09-18  |   12:05:00   |   38.15        | 38.099
2011-09-18  |   12:10:00   |   38.20        | 38.10
2011-09-18  |   12:15:00   |   38.22        | 38.17
2011-09-18  |   12:20:00   |   38.21        | 38.20
...
2011-09-19  |   11:50:00   |   38.17        | 38.10
2011-09-19  |   12:55:00   |   38.32        | 38.27
2011-09-19  |   12:00:00   |   38.30        | 38.20

Date/Time columns are of type date/time (and not datetime)

In another table (Table B) we store some data for the entire day, where a day is from NOON (12PM) to noon (not midnight to midnight).

So table B columns include:
Date (date only no time)
ShiftManager
MaxTemp (this is the max temp for the entire 24 hours starting at that date noon till next day noon)
MinTemp

I get table B with all the data and just need to update the MaxTemp and MinTemp using table A
For example:For 09/18/2011 I need the maximum temp reading that was between 09/18/2011 12PM and 09/19/2011 12PM.
In the TableA sample we have above, the returend result would be 38.32 as it is the MAX(MaxTemp) for the desired period.

The SQL I'm using:

```
update TableB
set MaxTemp = (
select MAX(HighTemp) from TableA
where
(Date=TableB.Date and Time > '12:00:00') 
or 
(Date=DATEADD(dd,1,TableB.Date) and Time <= '12:00:00')
)
```

And it takes a lot of time (if I remove the DATEADD method it is quick).

Here is a simplified sample that shows the data I have and the expected result:

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE ([Date] DATE, [Time] TIME(0), HighTemp DECIMAL(6,2));
DECLARE @TableB TABLE ([Date] DATE, MaxTemp DECIMAL(6,2));

INSERT @TableA VALUES
('2011-09-18','12:05:00',38.15),
('2011-09-18','12:10:00',38.20),
('2011-09-18','12:15:00',38.22),
('2011-09-19','11:50:00',38.17),
('2011-09-19','11:55:00',38.32),
('2011-09-19','12:00:00',38.31),
('2011-09-19','12:05:00',38.33),
('2011-09-19','12:10:00',38.40),
('2011-09-19','12:15:00',38.12),
('2011-09-20','11:50:00',38.27),
('2011-09-20','11:55:00',38.42),
('2011-09-20','12:00:00',38.16);

INSERT @TableB VALUES
('2011-09-18', 0),
('2011-09-19', 0);

-- This is how I get the data, now I just need to update the max temp for each day

with TableB(d, maxt) as
(
select * from @TableB
)
update TableB
set maxt = ( 
select MAX(HighTemp) from @TableA 
where
(Date=TableB.d and Time > '12:00:00')
or
(Date=DATEADD(dd,1,TableB.d) and Time <= '12:00:00')
)

select * from @TableB
```

Hope I was able to explian myself, any ideas how can I do it differently? Thx!

Comment: The curly brackets will format your code. Hint: 4 leading space...

Comment: Does TableB.Date go in with the default time of midnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably be a lot easier if you used a single `SMALLDATETIME` column instead of separating this data into `DATE`/`TIME` columns. Also I'm assuming you are using SQL Server 2008 and not a previous version where you're storing `DATE`/`TIME` data as strings. Please specify the version of SQL Server and the actual data types being used.

```
DECLARE @d TABLE ([Date] DATE, [Time] TIME(0), MaxTemp DECIMAL(6,3), MinTemp DECIMAL(6,3));

INSERT @d VALUES
('2011-09-18','12:05:00',38.15,38.099),
('2011-09-18','12:10:00',38.20,38.10),
('2011-09-18','12:15:00',38.22,38.17),
('2011-09-18','12:20:00',38.21,38.20),
('2011-09-19','11:50:00',38.17,38.10),
('2011-09-19','12:55:00',38.32,38.27),
('2011-09-19','12:00:00',38.30,38.20);

SELECT '-- before update';
SELECT * FROM @d;

;WITH d(d,t,dtr,maxt) AS
(
    SELECT [Date], [Time], DATEADD(HOUR, -12, CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), 
        [Date], 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), [Time], 108))), MaxTemp FROM @d 
),
d2(dtr, maxt) AS 
(
    SELECT CONVERT([Date], dtr), MAX(maxt) FROM d
    GROUP BY CONVERT([Date], dtr)
)
UPDATE d SET maxt = d2.maxt FROM d
    INNER JOIN d2 ON d.dtr >= d2.dtr AND d.dtr < DATEADD(DAY, 1, d2.dtr);

SELECT '-- after update';
SELECT * FROM @d;
```

Results:

```
-- before update

2011-09-18  12:05:00    38.150  38.099
2011-09-18  12:10:00    38.200  38.100
2011-09-18  12:15:00    38.220  38.170
2011-09-18  12:20:00    38.210  38.200
2011-09-19  11:50:00    38.170  38.100
2011-09-19  12:55:00    38.320  38.270
2011-09-19  12:00:00    38.300  38.200

-- after update

2011-09-18  12:05:00    38.220  38.099
2011-09-18  12:10:00    38.220  38.100
2011-09-18  12:15:00    38.220  38.170
2011-09-18  12:20:00    38.220  38.200
2011-09-19  11:50:00    38.220  38.100
2011-09-19  12:55:00    38.320  38.270
2011-09-19  12:00:00    38.320  38.200
```

Presumably you want to update the MinTemp as well, and that would just be:

```
;WITH d(d,t,dtr,maxt,mint) AS
(
    SELECT [Date], [Time], DATEADD(HOUR, -12,
         CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), [Date], 112) 
         + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), [Time], 108))), MaxTemp, MaxTemp
    FROM @d 
),
d2(dtr, maxt, mint) AS 
(
    SELECT CONVERT([Date], dtr), MAX(maxt), MIN(mint) FROM d
    GROUP BY CONVERT([Date], dtr)
)
UPDATE d
    SET maxt = d2.maxt, mint = d2.maxt
    FROM d
    INNER JOIN d2
        ON d.dtr >= d2.dtr
        AND d.dtr < DATEADD(DAY, 1, d2.dtr);
```

Now, this is not really better than your existing query, because it's still going to be using scans to figure out aggregates and all the rows that need to be updating. I'm not saying you *should* be updating the table at all, because this information can always be derived at query time, but if it is something you really want to do, I would combine the advice in these answers and consider revising the schema. For example, if the schema were:

```
USE [tempdb];
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.d
(
    [Date] SMALLDATETIME, 
    MaxTemp DECIMAL(6,3), 
    MinTemp DECIMAL(6,3),
    RoundedDate AS (CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -12, [Date]))) PERSISTED
);

CREATE INDEX rd ON dbo.d(RoundedDate);

INSERT dbo.d([Date],MaxTemp,MinTemp) VALUES
('2011-09-18 12:05:00',38.15,38.099),
('2011-09-18 12:10:00',38.20,38.10),
('2011-09-18 12:15:00',38.22,38.17),
('2011-09-18 12:20:00',38.21,38.20),
('2011-09-19 11:50:00',38.17,38.10),
('2011-09-19 12:55:00',38.32,38.27),
('2011-09-19 12:00:00',38.30,38.20);
```

Then your update is this simple, and the plan is much nicer:

```
;WITH g(RoundedDate,MaxTemp)
AS
(
    SELECT RoundedDate, MAX(MaxTemp)
        FROM dbo.d
        GROUP BY RoundedDate
)
UPDATE d
    SET MaxTemp = g.MaxTemp
    FROM dbo.d AS d
    INNER JOIN g
    ON d.RoundedDate = g.RoundedDate;
```

Finally, one of the reasons your existing query is probably taking so long is that you are updating all of time, every time. Is data from last week changing? Probably not. So why not limit the `WHERE` clause to recent data only? I see no need to go recalculate anything earlier than yesterday unless you are constantly receiving revised estimates of how warm it was last Tuesday at noon. So why are there no WHERE clauses on your current query, to limit the date range where it is attempting to do this work? Do you really want to update the WHOLE able, EVERY time? This is probably something you should only be doing once a day, sometime in the afternoon, to update yesterday. So whether it takes 2 seconds or 2.5 seconds shouldn't really matter.

Comment: I can't see what you're doing to get that error. Can you show the code somewhere? The code I listed above was tested, and I don't see anywhere where I'm using HOUR against a DATE (unless you changed it).

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad, I haven't noticed for the type that was smalldatetime.

I like the idea of the RoundDate, it works very well and help in other queries as well.
I do need a seperate date and time fields but I managed to create that computed field like so:
[RoundedDay]  AS (CONVERT([date],dateadd(hour,-12,CONVERT([datetime],[Date],0)+CONVERT([datetime],[Time],0)),0)) PERSISTED

What do you think?

Comment: You might want to use `DATEADD(MINUTE, -765,` based on some of the further queries I was trying based on your update. Also your formula doesn't seem right... did you try it? It seems like RoundedDay is the wrong day for the noon rows. And it will probably be a little more efficient if you use a clustered startdatetime column to start with, instead of the separate date / time columns. Those data types have their place but it doesn't seem to be beneficial in your case.

Comment: I tried it and it looks good. Don't worry about the exact math to use, I'll figure it out...
I think that I do need seperate date and time columns because I have many queries that I filter by time only, and group by date.
Like the average max temp between 7AM-10AM on each day etc.
I think it is easier to do that if I have a dedicated time field, no?

Comment: It is probably easier to derive the date and time from a single smalldatetime column (using computed columns or not) than to combine the date / time information from separate columns only to do the same. Indexes on that column (including non-clustered indexes that include it by definition, if it's the clustered index) will also be a lot skinnier.

Comment: But say that I dont have a seperate Date/Time columns and only a single smalldatetime column, how I would do the following:

    select * 
    from TableA 
where [Time]>"08:00:00" and [Time]<"10:00:00" group by [Date]'

Comment: It's kind of a toss-up, if you have to support range queries or shifting based on date and time together, and also queries based on date and time apart, you may be better off with a smalldatetime and date/time computed columns, or date/time columns and a smalldatetime computed column. Probably depends on which one you do more often... though I would lean toward storing the clustered value as one (smalldatetime) and having computed columns that extract the pieces. Less convoluted, keeps the clustered index smaller, extraction is easier than concatenation, single parameter for DML, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Functions on column usually kill performance. So can OR.

However, I assume you want AND not OR because it is a range.

So, applying some logic and having just one calculation

```
update TableB
 set MaxTemp =
 (
    select MAX(HighTemp) from TableA
    where
    (Date + Time - 0.5 = TableB.Date)
 )
```

`(Date + Time - 0.5)` will change noon to noon to be midnight to midnight (0.5 = 12 hours). More importantly, you can make this a [computed column and index it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx)

More correctly, `Date + Time - 0.5` is `DATEADD(hour, -12, Date+Time)` assuming `Date` and `Time` are real dates/times and not varchar...

Edit: this answer is **wrong** but I'll leave it up as "what not to do"

See this for more:

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Comment: Be careful with the shorthand for `DATEADD`. If any of the columns are the new date/time data types (`DATE`/`TIME`/`DATETIME2`/`DATETIMIEOFFSET`) it will fail with `Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 - Operand data type date is invalid for add operator.`

Comment: yes, that's true. Just trying to kick people's habits because the code will break if/when they migrate to the new data types, or someone comes along and is already using the new types, they may not understand the error. If you spell out `DATEADD` it works everywhere.

Comment: I assume Table B has no time component but table A does.  This would only match reading with a time of noon on TableB.  I think.

Comment: @BalamBalam: TableB has a date and OP wants to "round" Date+Time to nearest midnight

Comment: @GNB just a healthy question and I could be wrong but I tested this.  Yes the .5 made it noon but it sill did not match a row in TableA with a time of time of 10.21 AM or 2:53 PM.  It only matched to rows with time of exactly noon.  I am assuming that TableB is recording the actual time. In his slow query the condition is a date range.

Comment: Edited the question and tried to explain better, I'm not trying to convert noon-noon to midnight-midnight, I need to maximum temp reading that was in the noon-noon period.

Comment: @GNB you are right I missed that time was a separate column Sorry

Comment: @GNB I test on my SQL2008 and Date + Time - .5 does not round to a date rather it gives the exact time.  2008-08-13 04:29:00 became 2008-08-12 16:29:00.  I could easily have missed something.

Comment: @GNB and I am probably wrong again.  I tested using a DateTime column.   It suspect your answer works correctly if the columns are Date and Time.

Comment: @gbn responded to your comment on my blog post, in case you don't get notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use -12 depending on date as start date or end date for the noon to noon internal.

```
    update tableA 
    set tableAx.MaxTemp = MAX(TableB.HighTemp)
    from tableA as tableAx
    join TableB 
    on tableAx.Date = CAST(DATEADD(hh,12,TableB.[Date]+TableB.[Time]) as Date) 
    group by tableAx.Date
```

Because of the 12 hour offset not sure how much would would gain by putting TableB Date plus Time in a DateTime field directly.  Cannot get away from the DATEADD and the output from a functions is not indexed even if the parameters going into the function are indexed.  What you might be able to to is create a computed column that = date + time +/- 12h and index that column.

Like the recommendation from Arron to only update those without values.

```
    update tableA 
    set tableAx.MaxTemp = MAX(TableB.HighTemp)
    from tableA as tableAx
    join TableB 
    on tableAx.Date = CAST(DATEADD(hh,12,TableB.[Date]+TableB.[Time]) as Date) 
    where tableAx.MaxTemp is null 
    group by tableAx.Date
```

or an insert of new dates

```
    insert into tableA (date, MaxTemp) 
    select CAST(DATEADD(hh,12,TableB.[Date]+TableB.[Time]), as Date) as [date] , MAX(TableB.HighTemp) as [MaxTemp]
    from tableA as tableAx
    right outer join TableB 
    on tableAx.Date = CAST(DATEADD(hh,12,TableB.[Date]+TableB.[Time]) as Date) 
    where TableB.Date is null 
    group by CAST(DATEADD(hh,12,TableB.[Date]+TableB.[Time]) as Date)
```